# std::shared_ptr calls non-default deleter on null pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, reference-counting

See this example :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo()  { std::cout << "Foo()\n";  }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "~Foo()\n"; }
};

int main(){
    auto deleter = [](Foo* p) {
        if(!p) { std::cout << "Calling deleter on nullptr\n"; }
        delete p;
    };

    std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo;
    std::cout << "\nWith non-null Foo:\n";
    foo = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo, deleter);
    std::cout << "foo is " << (foo ? "not ":"") << "null\n";
    std::cout << "use count=" << foo.use_count() << '\n';
    foo.reset();

    std::cout << "\nWith nullptr and deleter:\n";
    foo = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(nullptr, deleter);
    std::cout << "foo is " << (foo ? "not ":"") << "null\n";
    std::cout << "use count=" << foo.use_count() << '\n';
    foo.reset();

    std::cout << "\nWith nullptr, without deleter:\n";
    foo = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(nullptr);
    std::cout << "foo is " << (foo ? "not ":"") << "null\n";
    std::cout << "use count=" << foo.use_count() << '\n';
    foo.reset();
}
```

The output is :

```
With non-null Foo:
Foo()
foo is not null
use count=1
~Foo()

With nullptr and deleter:
foo is null
use count=1
Calling deleter on nullptr

With nullptr, without deleter:
foo is null
use count=0
```

Here we see that `shared_ptr` calls the contained deleter when it is initialized with `nullptr` and a custom deleter.
It seems that, when initialized with a custom deleter, `shared_ptr` considers it is "owning" nullptr and thus tries to delete it when it would delete any other owned pointer. Though it does not happen when no deleter is specified.

Is this intended behavior ? If so, what is the reason behind this behavior ?

Comment: `delete(nullptr)` is, afaik, completely valid, so it makes sense that, for any value given to a `shared_ptr`, it'll call the deleter it's given, without wasting cycles checking if it's `nullptr`

Comment: `Unlike std::unique_ptr, the deleter of std::shared_ptr is invoked even if the managed pointer is null.` [Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/~shared_ptr)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962978/boost-smart-pointer-with-custom-deleter

Comment: @PhilM That's actually not [what the standard says](http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared#dest-1.2), though by the as-if rule (when no deleter is given) it may do as you describe

Comment: Hmm, just realised https://stackoverflow.com/a/11164463/560648 is probably a dupe

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This question's answer also partially answers my question (that is, yes, it is intended), though I still think this is a different question. Also, it does not tell me why this behavior is intended.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1450.html isn't vastly helpful in that regard

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr: Yes, it's intended.**

---

This is pretty subtle.

A shared_ptr can be in two states:

- "empty": default-constructed or reset; holds no ownership; `get()` may return `nullptr` (although [some ctors exist which change this postcondition](http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared#const-17))
- not empty: holds ownership of a pointer `p`; `get()` returns `p`.

Constructing a `shared_ptr` with a null pointer *actually leads to it being not-empty*! `get()` returning `p` means `get()` returning `nullptr`, but that doesn't make it empty.

Since the default deleter just does `delete p`, and `delete nullptr` is a no-op, this doesn't usually matter. But, as you have seen, you can observe this difference if you provide your own deleter.

I don't know exactly *why* this is. On the one hand I can see a case for preventing a deleter from being invoked in the nullptr case because one generally considers a `shared_ptr(nullptr)` to be "empty" (even though it technically is not); on the other hand, I can see a case for letting the deleter make this decision (with the accompanying overhead of a branch) if it wants to.

You're right to include a check for null here.

---

Some legalese from `[util.smartptr.shared.const]`:

> **`template<class Y, class D> shared_ptr(Y* p, D d);`**
>   **`template<class Y, class D, class A> shared_ptr(Y* p, D d, A a);`**
>   **`template<class D> shared_ptr(nullptr_t p, D d);`**
>   **`template<class D, class A> shared_ptr(nullptr_t p, D d, A a);`**
>
> 9) Requires: Construction of `d` and a deleter of type `D` initialized with `std::move(d)` shall not throw exceptions. The expression `d(p)` shall have well-defined behavior and shall not throw exceptions. A shall satisfy the Cpp17Allocator requirements (Table 34).
>
> 10) Effects: **Constructs a `shared_­ptr` object that owns the object `p` and the deleter `d`.** When `T` is not an array type, the first and second constructors enable `shared_­from_­this` with `p`. The second and fourth constructors shall use a copy of `a` to allocate memory for internal use. If an exception is thrown, `d(p)` is called.
>
> 11) Ensures: **`use_­count() == 1 && get() == p`.**

*(Notice that there is no exemption for the case that `!p`.)*

And from `[util.smartptr.shared.dest]`:

> **`~shared_ptr();`**
>
> 1) Effects:
>
> - If `*this` is empty or shares ownership with another `shared_­ptr` instance (`use_­count() > 1`), there are no side effects.
> - Otherwise, **if `*this` owns an object `p` and a deleter `d`, `d(p)` is called.**
> - Otherwise, `*this` owns a pointer `p`, and `delete p` is called.

Sidenote: I think the confusion between the phrases "owns an object" and "owns a pointer" in the above passages is an editorial problem.

---

We can also see this documented on [cppreference.com's `~shared_ptr` article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/~shared_ptr):

> Unlike `std::unique_ptr`, the deleter of `std::shared_ptr` is invoked even if the managed pointer is null.

(Please use documentation!)

Comment: You're an exemption.

Comment: `template<class Y, class D> shared_ptr(Y* p, D d);` mandates that `delete p` is a valid op and by defeault `delete nullptr` is. If the custom deleter can't handle that then it doesn't make sense to pass `nullptr` to `sharedptr`

Comment: an empty `shared_ptr` may have a non-null stored pointer if the aliasing constructor was used to create it - see http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared#const-17

Comment: @SamerTufail Correct.

Comment: @yachoor Thanks!

Comment: A null `shared_ptr` may be used to execute arbitrary code: `shared_ptr<void> guard(static_cast<void*>(0), bind(f, x, y))` - from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#techniques_using_shared_ptr_to_execute_code_on_block_exit

Comment: Sorry, I did use the documentation, but I did not think to look at the destructor, since the deletor seemed to be called in `reset()` I only looked this page and did not see anything. I also made the wrong assumption that a `shared_ptr` pointing to nullptr was empty. I'm pretty close to accept this answer, but if you can find a reason why shared_ptr does not check if it holds nullptr, it would be perfect. (I'm just being curious there, because unique_ptr does check that)

Comment: @Annyo I've given it a go but to be honest I don't think I'll be able to. Hopefully someone with more time can give it a better go and get luckier!